# JOIN data from 2 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a question about joining the data from 2 tables from a MySQL Database. First I will explain what I currently have and then what I want just to be as clear as possible.

I have 2 tables in the Database which look like this:

```
Table: Subscriptions
Columns:
ID          int(11) PK AI
Klant ID    int(11) 
Mail ID     int(11) 
Status      varchar(15) 
Datum       varchar(15)

ID   Klant_ID Mail_ID Status Datum
123  6        6       90     21-03-2013
124  6        6       10     21-03-2013
125  6        5       90     21-03-2013
126  6        5       10     21-03-2013
127  6        1       90     20-03-2013
128  6        1       10     20-03-2013
129  6        2       10     21-03-2013
130  6        2       90     21-03-2013
131  6        4       90     21-03-2013
132  6        4       10     21-03-2013
```

And:

```
Table: Mail
Columns:
ID  int(11) PK AI
Content longtext 
Datum   varchar(15) 
Titel   varchar(150) 

ID  Content                 Datum       Titel
1   (alot of encoded html)  18-03-13    test
2   (alot of encoded html)  18-03-13    test2
4   (alot of encoded html)  18-03-13    alles weer testen
5   (alot of encoded html)  20-03-13    testje
6   (alot of encoded html)  21-03-13    Statusupdate week 6
```

I am using these 2 queries to select the data from the tables now:

```
SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail
SELECT * FROM Subscriptions,
(SELECT MAX(ID) as ids, Mail_ID FROM Subscriptions
    WHERE Klant_ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."' GROUP BY Mail_ID) table2
WHERE ID=table2.ids
```

I want to get a query using JOIN to be able to create this table using html:

[image]

I personaly haven't got much experience using JOIN since I first used it yesterday, I am able to make a simple JOIN query but I just don't know how to do this. If you have more questions ask them in the comments. If anyone could help me with this it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple Join between your tables

```
SELECT Mail_ID, Titel, Status, Subscriptions.Datum FROM Subscriptions
JOIN Mail ON (Subscription.Mail_ID=Mail.ID)
    WHERE Klant_ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."' GROUP BY Mail_ID
```

the order of the rows is random by a join,
if you want to get the last data, your query is right.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select mail.id, mail.titel, subscriptions.status, subscriptions.datum
from mail join subscriptions on mail.id = subscriptions.mail_id
```

Comment: The simplest and quickest way was provide by @JaMaBing, but if you have many same name of field like `Datum` on yours, you need to give an alias to the tables and column you wanna select on.

Answer (score 0):

Tyvm @kolonel peteruk, @Kaii and @JaMaBing for your answers!

With your help I was able to merge my query with yours. I finally got it to work using this query:

```
SELECT Mail.ID, Mail.Titel, Subscriptions.ID, Subscriptions.Status, Subscriptions.Datum,      Subscriptions.Mail_ID, Subscriptions.Mail_ID, Subscriptions.Klant_ID 
FROM NAW.Subscriptions
JOIN NAW.Mail 
ON Mail.ID = Subscriptions.Mail_ID, 
(SELECT MAX(Subscriptions.ID) as ids, Mail_ID 
FROM NAW.Subscriptions
WHERE Klant_ID =6  
GROUP BY Mail_ID) table2
WHERE Subscriptions.ID=table2.ids
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ID ,e.Titel,ea.Status,ea.Datum 
    FROM Mail e 
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions ea 
            ON e.ID = ea.Mail_ID
            WHERE ea.Klant_ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."' 
            GROUP BY Mail_ID)
    ORDER BY e.ID ASC
```